# BASH: ping function looping

Tags: bash

My ping function seems to loop.
Does anybody know why?

Bash-x output:

> ++ PING='ping -q -c1'
>   ++ ping -q -c1 -q
>   ++ TEMPIP=-q
>   ++ PING='ping -q -c1'
>   ++ ping -q -c1 -q
>   ++ TEMPIP=-q
>   ++ PING='ping -q -c1'
>   ++ ping -q -c1 -q
>   ++ TEMPIP=-q
>   ++ PING='ping -q -c1'

Code:

```
IP1="10.1.1.2"
IP2="10.1.1.3" 
IP3="10.1.1.4"
SEC=300

function ping {
   TEMPIP="$1"
   PING="ping -q -c1"

   ${PING} ${TEMPIP}

   if [ $? -ne 0 ]
   then 
       echo 1
   else
       echo 0
   fi

}

  function resetrouter {
  #dosomething
}

function check {
    IP1result=$(ping $IP1)
    IP2result=$(ping $IP2)
    IP3result=$(ping $IP3)
}
```

check

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you have called it `ping`, and the name of the command you want to run is also called `ping`, meaning it is recursively executing the function, instead of invoking the actual command called `ping`.

Rename the function `ping` to some other name.

Comment: Or, you can use the built-in command `command` to bypass the function.  But that's mostly useful for code obfuscation; renaming is better.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to call your function `ping` then you should use the full path to the `ping` command inside the function. You can find this out by calling:

```
$ which ping
/usr/bin/ping
```

So `PING="ping -q -c1"` would become `PING="/usr/bin/ping -q -c1"`